# How to control the size of a displayed image in a github repository?

Tags: git, github, github-flavored-markdown

Github uses [markdown language](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) to add an image.

1. Create a directory in the repository (e.g. `Image/`) to store the
   image file.
2. Refer to that image by using markdown language `![MyPicText](/Image/MyPicName.png)`

This [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHbWF1Bvgf4) shows that html language, i.e. `<img scr="/Image/MyPicName.png" width="100">`, may be used to display and control of the size of the selected image.

I have tried it but the image did not even appear. Also I did not get any error message. Instead, I discovered that an invisible hyperlink exist in its place.

How should I control the size of a displayed image in a github repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented in [this example](https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109#gistcomment-1880104):

> Github doesn't apply the style attribute but obeys the width and height.
> So for GitHub, you can use the following HTML tag directly in the markdown:

```
<img src="url" alt="alt text" width="whatever" height="whatever">
```

See also [GFM Image](https://github.github.com/gfm/#images): nothing about size.

The OP confirms it works:

> It is suppose to be `src` and not `scr` which I wrote.

Comment: I wrote the following forms but they all did not work. 
`<img alt="Default" scr="Pictures/VerticalScrollFrame_default.png" width="100">`,     `<img alt="Default" scr="tkinterWidgets/Pictures/VerticalScrollFrame_default.png" width="100">` and    `<img alt="Default" scr="https://github.com/sunbearc22/tkinterWidgets/blob/master/Pictures/VerticalScrollFrame_default.png" width="100">`. The failed outcomes can be seen [here](https://github.com/sunbearc22/tkinterWidgets/blob/master/README.md). Can you advise me what is wrong here? The GFM versions does appear but GFM does not allow size control.

Comment: @SunBear "GFM does not allow size control.": yes, that is what my answer is saying.

Comment: @SunBear Can you try with `?raw=true` at the end of your URLs? Like `https://github.com/sunbearc22/tkinterWidgets/blob/master/Pictures/VerticalScrollFrame_default.png?raw=true`

Comment: I tried `?raw=true` at the end of the above 3 links and still have the same error. Strange.

Comment: @SunBear In your source code for the generated page, the src attribute of the img element is missing. Just to be sure, try and close those img elements: `<img src="..." alt... />`  not the file `/>`

Comment: Thanks to you help. You are spot on. It is suppose to be `src` and not `scr` which I wrote.